AWS Config - track unsupported resource in different region
In AWS documentation Supported Resource Types there is statement about recording unsupported resource.

If a resource type is supported by AWS Config in at least one Region, you can enable the recording of that resource type in all Regions supported by AWS Config, even if the specified resource type is not supported in the AWS Region where you set up AWS Config.

However, I didn't find any option on how to enable such functionality, neither in console nor in API. For example, according to the Resource Coverage by Region Availability, resource "AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate" is not supported in Seoul. How can I enable tracking of that resource from e.g. Ireland?

TL;DR
You can't track EC2 LaunchTemplate in the Seul region.

If the region and the resource type are supported by AWS Config, I think what you need is AWS Config Aggregator, which enables multi-account and multi-region data collection.
One of the use cases of an AWS Config Aggregator is:

(...) track changes to resources over time across your organization, or across accounts and Regions

Here's how to set up one either via the Console or the CLI.
Make sure the region you want to collect data from is supported and combine this with resorce coverage by region.
However, in your case, the Seul region is supported when it comes to Aggregators, but the resource you want to track EC2 LaunchTemplate is not covered, which means you can't track it in that particular region.
